# Article Modelからデータを引っ張ってきたときの#<Article:0x9fhu3u...>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Modelからデータを引っ張ってきたとき,ブラウザで確認すると
Article:0x9fhu3u...と表示されます。
これは、データベースからデータがオブジェクトの16進数で帰ってきているという解釈で良いでしょうか。なぜこのような形になるのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= blog %>` のように書くと、`<%= blog.to_s %>`を書いたことと同じになります。

16進数の部分はデータベースのデータというより、モデルのインスタンスのobject_idをベースにした値が表示されています。
下のコードのように object_id を左に1ビットシフトし（2倍しても同じです）、その値を16進数表示すると、 to_s と同じ値が得られます。（厳密には to_s には "0x00" が付いていますが）

```
>> blog.to_s 
"#<Blog:0x007f83fa09a328>"
>> blog.object_id 
70102406189460
>> (blog.object_id << 1).to_s(16)
"7f83fa09a328"
```

ちなみに to_sの結果がこのようになるのは、Railsの仕様ではなく、Ruby標準の挙動です。

参考：

- [Class: Object (Ruby 2.2.3)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s)
- [In Ruby, why does inspect() print out some kind of object id which is different from what object_id() gives? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818602/in-ruby-why-does-inspect-print-out-some-kind-of-object-id-which-is-different)